# Why is MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP not recorded consistently?

Tags: android, multi-touch, motionevent

I thought pinch would always trigger MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP, but it happens only about 50% of the time (it varies a lot) for an app on at least two tested tablet devices. It appears to be random. I do not know how to pinch to make it happen consistently.

The code is very straightforward as the following overridden method of the activity in question:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
    ...
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

        Log.d("Debug", "ACTION_POINTER_UP triggered");
    default:
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may change your code to use [getActionMasked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionMasked%28%29).

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked())
    {
    //...
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

        Log.d("Debug", "ACTION_POINTER_UP triggered");
    default:
        break;
    }
    //...
}
```

---

MotionEven [getAction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getAction%28%29) reports an integer which consists of **both** ACTION_*whatever* and 
the pointer index left-shifted by ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT (8) bits.

> Return the kind of action being performed. Consider using getActionMasked() and getActionIndex() to retrieve the separate masked action and pointer index.
>
> Returns
>   The action, such as ACTION_DOWN or the combination of ACTION_POINTER_DOWN with a shifted pointer index.

getAction() can be quite confusing to work with in multi-touch situations. If you want to get the kind of action (ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, and so on), which your case most likely is, you may use `getActionMasked()` instead of `getAction()`.

- `getActionMasked()` always returns ACTION_*whatever*, without the pointer index bits.
- `getAction()` returns `(getActionIndex() << 8 | ACTION_whatever)`.
  *(pointer indexes are very counter-intuitive, with Android trying to re-use the lowest indices available giving strange behavior if you use them directly, but that's another story, here better use getActionMasked() and not worry about indices)*. This is numerically equal to `getActionMasked()` only when the pointer has index=0, therefore you will see the "random" behavior: As you complete each pinch "naturally",

  - sometimes you may have released pointer 0 first, then pointer 1 last,
    you get 2 events that getAction() returns ACTION_POINTER_UP followed by `1<<8 | ACTION_UP` respectively, and hits the `case ACTION_POINTER_UP` label on the first event.
  - The other time you may have released pointer 1 first, then pointer 0 last,
    you get 2 events that getAction() return `1<<8 | ACTION_POINTER_UP` followed by ACTION_UP.
    There is no case label for these, all get down to the `default`.
- If you use getActionMasked(), you get ACTION_POINTER_UP followed by ACTION_UP, in both cases consistently.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the detailed elucidation.  After taking your advice, the app catches 100% ACTION_POINTER_UP.

Comment: I have fallen for this trap before... The method name getAction() is so (perhaps intentionally so as to maintain backward "incompatibility" for non-multitouch-expecting apps?) misleading.

Comment: It has certainly misled me. Thanks again. What a relief to this resolved.